# Post Aptitude upgraded and my pi is unable to boot up properly

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-jessie, boot-issues

I'm currently using Raspbian Jessie and I recently updated and ran `sudo aptitude upgrade` it had a few things to upgrade and one removal which seemed normal.

During the upgrade, the display disappeared and the rainbow screen that appears briefly when the pi boots is all I get now.

The yellow light is flashing a few times in quick succession with a pause and then repeats. Any ideas how I can get the Pi to boot up, or get some error message out of it so I can post it here and/or search for a solution?

Comment: The yellow LED signifies the Pi is connected to Ethernet. What do the other LEDs on the Pi do when it boots up?

Comment: The other light turns red and stays like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I've run "aptitude upgrade" in a Raspbian Jessie (20151121), process breaks when loses /var/lib/dpkg/info/pimixer.postrm and both /bin and /dev directories disappear.

Some package script removes directories in root until removal command is not available.